# How to deploy the torque on mesos

Tags: mesos, torque

I want to deploy the torque and mpi on mesos, I know the mesos support mpi and torque for working. However, I can't find the detail in latest official document or github(mpi is found and torque is none). Is mesos not supported the torque for latest version?
Thank you!